# Restarting sidekiq jobs on reboot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq, rails-activejob

Currently I'm restarting my sidekiq jobs using a cron job that triggers the method below

```
class RestartSidekiqJobs
  require 'sidekiq/api'

  class << self
    def restart_jobs
      Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new.clear
      channels = Channel.all
      channels.each do |channel|
        FetchMoreDataJob.perform_later(channel: channel)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'm not convinced however that this is the best way to handle this so I figured I'd see if there were better solutions out there.